# Combining jQuery functions into one function

Tags: jquery

I am making a kind of job board and there are two modals to be triggered from one page NOT in the same time. I have created these functions to trigger the modals. Can You please suggest me how to write it the shortest way (if its possible). Thank You.
so this is main part of my html code:

```
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <a id="test" href="#destination">FIRST modal</a>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="destination"></div>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <h3>First Modal</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  <!-- END First -->

                    <a id="test2" href="#destination2">SECOND modal</a>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="destination2"></div>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                    <h3>Second Modal</h3>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  <!-- END Second -->
```

and Jquery I would like to "shorten"

```
jQuery(function (){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
    $('#test2').click(function(){
        $('#myModal2').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: Providing HTML markup would help for sure... Now i guess, you could just use classes and index to target specific one modal

Comment: What's wrong with the current one?

Comment: the problem is that I will have 20 modals or more to be triggered and I am thinking if I can make it shorter.

Comment: @HubertKubasiewicz if you're able to change the HTML markup, you can add a data-modalId attribute, then you can make a generic jQuery function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your HTML, your elements `#test` and `#test2` have a `data-id` attribute for example, you can do :

```
jQuery(function (){
    $('#test, #test2').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('#myModal'+id).modal('show');
    });
});
```

If an element have `data-id` attribute to 2, this function open the modal `#myModal2`

Comment: So I have in first modal id=test and id=myModal and in second modal id=test2 and id=myModal2. And if I copy Your suggestion in 100% nothing is working but if I delete "+id" it is working but only the first modal is triggered if I click the first or the second option.

Comment: Edit your post and past your HTML please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DRY principle to tidy your code. Firstly use a common class on the element which triggers the modal, along with a `data-*` attribute to store the unique relationship for that element.

```
<button type="button" class="test" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
<button type="button" class="test" data-target="#myModal2">Open modal #2</button>
```

Then you can read that `data` attribute in your click handler to call `modal()` on the correct element:

```
jQuery(function (){
    $('.test').click(function(){
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $(target).modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to have a button, I want people to be able to click on the job title and in this moment the modal to be triggered. I have reach this effect so far but I would like to have the js file as short as possible. Maybe its not a good idea, and it should be like I have written.

Comment: The `button` is just an example. The technique can be applied to any HTML you want to use. If you edit your question to include your current HTML I can give you a more complete example

Comment: ok so now I have changed my links into buttons as You suggest and its working, so now I have to change buttons into text and it should be fine.

Comment: <a id="test" href="#destination" data-target="#myModal">FIRST modal</a>

Comment: OK now its working I was missing data-toggle="modal" :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Although note that your `<a>` elements need the class of `test` for my code above to work